# Eigenvalues of minors to Schrodinger matrices

Tags: eigenvalues, schrodinger-operators

Suppose that we have a graph $G$, define the hamiltonian $H$ on it as $$Hu(x) = \sum_{y\sim x}u(y).$$ Consider the operator $H+V$ where $V$ multiplies the value $u(x)$ in any vertex by the potential in that vertex. Any minor of $H+V+\lambda$ is a polynomial of $\lambda.$ Is it true that it has only real eigenvalues? Consider the dependence of ONE of these eigenvalues on $V$. What bounds on the derivatives $\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial V(x)}$ of the minors' eigenvalues are known?

Comment: By the eigenvalues of the minor you mean the zeros of this polynomial?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the zeros of the polynomial